# How to create a PDF file from a dict() data in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, pdf-conversion

I have got a Dict from a .txt data, and I want to create a PDF file with this data.

How can I create it?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Improved the wording. Please edit the question to show an example of your dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pip install pdfkit
```

Also install wkhtmltopdf:

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

Then in your code:

```
import pdfkit
import json
pdfkit.from_string(json.dumps(yourdict))
```

You could also do:

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_file('your.txt', 'out.pdf')
```

Comment: pdfkit.from_file didn't work for me with html file. 'No file found' was the error I got. Does anybody know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Give it the whole path to the file